# jQuery position().top returns 0 rather than real value

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to the jQuery official documentation, this function should:

**"Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent."**

The following code is expected to return value 51, but it returns value 0. Could anyone provide insight as too why? Thanks in advance.

I know that adding css(top:xx) works, if so, does that mean position() only work for the case the element has the css property of top?

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .outer
        {
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            overflow-y:auto;
            border:1px dotted grey;
            position:absolute;
        }
        .inner
        {
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            margin-top:  50px;
            border:1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.inner').mousedown(function (e) {
                alert($(this).position().top);
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use offset().top http://jsfiddle.net/XpynZ/

Comment: @sofl  this is relative to the document, I want to the get the length between inner div and outer div, that is to say I need use position rather than offset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The API description is correct. The inner element has the (initial) default CSS property value of `top:auto`. There is a `margin-top:50px` which as you know is giving the impression that the inner element is `50px` from the top, but this is not the case. jQuery will return `position().top = 0` since the element's top really is `0px` from the parent element.

For jQuery to return an expected value using the [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) function you would need to position the inner `<div>` relatively (or absolute depending on your needs) to the parent and supply a top value and remove the `margin-top` property, for example:

```
.inner {
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Is this helping you?:

`document.getElementById("innerDiv").offsetTop;`

Or use the jquery [Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) Method:

> The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an
>   element relative to the document. Contrast this with .position(),
>   which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent.
>   When positioning a new element on top of an existing one for global
>   manipulation (in particular, for implementing drag-and-drop),
>   .offset() is the more useful.

Comment: Ok, sry i was to quick with my guess, I'm simmulation your problem now in firefox and it sais indeed 0 instead of a value. I'm looking what it could be.

Comment: Ankit is right, check out this working example with relative positioning instead of margin: http://jsfiddle.net/HPSLm/

Comment: I know that adding css(top:xx) works, if so, does that mean position() only work for the case the element has the css property of top?

Answer (score 5):

It is alerting 0 which is 100% correct , because top only returns values other that 0 when you are using them to position an element but here you are using margins and padding to position element so use them to get the top distance.Like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.inner').mousedown(function (e) {
                alert($(this).css("margin-top"));
            })
        })
```

If you want to use position then do it

```
.inner
        {   position:absolute;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            top:  50px;
            border:1px solid red;
        }
```

and then do your normal coding

Comment: thanks. I know this way is feasible, but it is not what I want.  I just want to use position().

Comment: I know that adding css(top:xx) works, if so, does that mean position() only work for the case the element has the css property of top?

Comment: pardon? I don't understand what you mean